# How to search for tasks and events in Mozilla Lightning/Thunderbird?

Tags: thunderbird, search, tasks, events, lightning

I can't find this function nowhere yet reading [this](http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?p=3292113#p3292113) post from ssitter in [Integrate Unifinder into Lightning as it is in Sunbird](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=372829) bug in Mozilla's Bugzilla it looks like it was already implemented 3 years ago.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There is no integrated search as far as I know. However, there is a rather good search function in Lightning, you can access it under the main menu > Events and Tasks > Find events.

A search bar along with a list of events will appear on top of your main calendar view. You can filter the search criteria on a time basis and expand the events information (and sort the events accordingly) by adding columns to the list as you would in the message list pane.

Answer (score 0):

In the tasks pane of Thunderbird you have a `Filter tasks` search bar in the top right of the tab (also accessible with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd>). It will search into the currently displayed tasks.

You can select on the left part of the screen which tasks are displayed and thus will be searched to (`Current`, `Today`, `Complete`, `All`, ...)